# How do I efficiently load someone's steam inventory and price of their every item on my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, steam, steam-web-api

I am running Node.js server and I want to load user's inventory so they can see their item and values of each item using JavaScript. I have tried to approach this problem by making multiple XHR request. First request requests user's items and the others are for each item to get their value. Of course, having this much XMLHttpRequests causes problems, and I am not able to get all of the items displayed if any. How should I get this working? Should I store player's inventory instead of loading it every time? But what if the contents change? Also, I need to find a way for getting price of each item more efficiently. Should I store prices somewhere in my database?

I'm using following APIs

Get inventory contents: [https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{STEAMID}/inventory/json/730/2](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/%7BSTEAMID%7D/inventory/json/730/2)
Get price of item: [https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name={ITEM'S](https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=%7BITEM%27S) MARKET_HASH_NAME}

Answer (score 0):

The market/priceoverview endpoint has a very low rate limit and you probably don't want to call it every time you need the price of an item. Storing the result in a database is definitely a good start but depending on how many items you want to track that wont be enough. A good workaround would be to use a third party API. Either use prices from a different marketplace, which provides an API to get the prices for all your item's in a single call or an API which provides cached data from Steam.
[CSGO Trader](https://csgotrader.app/) provides an API which combines prices over the most common marketplaces (including the Steam Market). `https://prices.csgotrader.app/latest/prices_v6.json` hosts a list for all CS:GO Items which is updated every 8 hours. For Market Data of other app's you depend on Services like [SteamApis](https://steamapis.com/).